# Visual Studio 2017 MVC Application Debug F5 works fine but Ctrl + F5 doesn't

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-debugging

I am using Visual Studio 2017. When I debug my application it works fine i.e. Session is being cleared and data is being populated one by one on every POST. 
But when I run application without debugging i.e. Ctrl + F5. It prepopulates data from previous session.
I tried by clearing session, cookies and cache but it is not working.

Comment: To clear session I used :    
Session.Clear();    
Session.RemoveAll();      

To clear cache:    
this.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1));    
this.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);    
this.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();      

and to clear cookie I applied:    
this.Request.Cookies.Clear();      


Can anyone please help on this.

Comment: Hi, can you share [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which will help us troubleshoot your issue?

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution, problem is because of a static variable not because of cache or session or cookie.

In my application I was using a static variable. Which clears its value on F5 not on ctrl + F5. 
Along with that if I clean solution and then did Ctrl + F5 it works.
So, I removed that static variable and used a local variable..
And all works well.

Hope if anyone have similar problem. it will work for them too.